# Chrome extension - cache JSON file for 1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome Extension decides whether to activate based on a JSON whitelist. This file is currently retrieved using the function below. What I'd like to do, is store the file for a certain amount of time, let's say 1 day, even if the browser would be closed in the meanwhile. What is the best way to do this?

Code for request:

```
jQuery.getJSON( "https://www.example.com/whitelist.json" ) //cache this file
  .done(function( data ) {
    jQuery.each(data.configs, function(key, val) {
        showMenu();
        return
    })
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
  });
```

Comment: Could you store it in localStorage with an attribute that holds an expiry date? Check localStorage first and if it's not there or out of date you can retrieve the JSON via AJAX.

Comment: Why you don't save this file content in `localStorage` what you say?

Comment: Did some research and I guess localStorage could fit very well, yes. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Use session_set_cookie_parameters() to give the session cookie a non-zero lifetime before starting the session, or set session.cookie_lifetime to non-zero.
you can try this option..
All the best.

Comment: The session would be closed as soon as the browser is closed, so unfortunately that wouldn't help.